# How to handle web design form to center page and copyright to bottom-center using bootstrap.css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried a couple hours to find how to do that, but not yet how to do

I've a form like this that i though it's not good-looking:

[image]

then I try how to set a form to center page and `footer.php` to bottom-center

`form.php`

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <div class="well">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h3>Tambah Nilai Preferensi</h3>
            </div>

                <form method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="kt">Keterangan Nilai</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kt" name="kt" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="jm">Jumlah Nilai</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jm" name="jm" required>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
                  <button type="button" onclick="location.href='nilai.php'" class="btn btn-success">Kembali</button>
                </form>

          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

`footer.php`

```
<footer class="text-center">&copy; 2017</footer>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#tabeldata').DataTable();

        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and for some class in `bootstrap.css` I've found is this

```
.well {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.well blockquote {
  border-color: #ddd;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.well-lg {
  padding: 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.well-sm {
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Change this line `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">` to this `<div class="col-xs-12">` - this will create only one column for the the page in all screen resolutions.  Since you are new at this, I recommend also reading about **[bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)** - Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: @ochi but it's take's a form [like this](http://imgur.com/uO2RtEG), i want to keep the form size

Comment: then you could add a 3-col, 6-col, 3-col pattern... let me see if I can cook up an answer with what you want... give me a few mins

Comment: @ochi I found [this link](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns) but the `col-centered` is not working :( , also for another way, i just add col-xs-offset-3 to set form centered, but i though it's just for my desktop resolution

Comment: try using this `<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"> ` - see running answer below

Comment: did you add the same class definition to your CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to offset your starting point.  Like this;

`<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">`

**See demo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <div class="well">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Tambah Nilai Preferensi</h3>
      </div>

      <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="kt">Keterangan Nilai</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kt" name="kt" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="jm">Jumlah Nilai</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jm" name="jm" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="location.href='nilai.php'" class="btn btn-success">Kembali</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So `col-xs-offset-#` is not just for my resolution??

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Please read about the grid system in bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) it has a good explanation on how it works